# Lock mifare ultralight page?

Tags: android, nfc

Is it possible that using the NFC Capabilities of Android to lock a memory page for beeing written to in the future ?

Thank you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan looked at it better found the solution closed as the question was stupid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing specific to Android. If the page can be locked by modifying the relevant lock bits, and you have access (key for Ultralight-C, etc.), it is only a matter of sending a properly set up write command. Check the MFU manual for details.